# gcc fails to optimize identity function to nop

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, clang

It seems that while clang 3.4.2 can optimize `foo` to a no-op, gcc 4.9.1 cannot and will generate over a dozen instructions.  Tested on x86-64 with `-O3`.

I would assume the optimization is a safe one since the struct is not declared `volatile`.  Is there some flag that allows this to be optimized away?

```c
struct s { /* arbitrary struct */
    long long m1;
    char m2[235];
    int m3;
    double m4;
};

static struct s bar(struct s x) {
    return x;
}

void foo(struct s *x) {
    *x = bar(*x);
}
```

Comment: Report gcc bugs on the gcc forums

Comment: Returning aggregate types by value, especially large ones, is generally considered a bad practice in C. I wouldn't be surprised if the reason this is not optimized is just that nobody has cared about this behavior until now.

Comment: @R..: It's not something I would write by hand though, but that could be a reason.

Comment: “Is there some flag that allows this to be optimized away?” Does marking `bar` as `inline` count as a “flag”?

Comment: @Pascal_Cuoq: Not even `always_inline` works here.

Comment: Would marking `foo` as `static` accomplish anything? Wondering if it has something to do with "might be called from a different compilation unit"... Still, it could compile to a simple `ret` instead of a bunch of instructions...

Comment: If `foo` is also `static` this entire module would compile to nothing.